# Using cron with ssh keys

Tags: bash, ssh, cron, rsync

I am using a cron script that rsyncs with a server via ssh.

The commands work great when I run them directly as a bash script, but when I run them as cron, cron logs out bad permissions. I think this is because the cron user does not have access to the ssh key.

This is the code that I need cron to run:

```
rsync --progress -rvze ssh my_user@myserver/root_folder folder/
```

Can I pass the ssh key into the cronfile, or into the script itself? If so, would you provide an example like the one above?

Comment: Have you specified to run the script as root in `crontab` ?

Comment: Which user does it work for and which user did you make cron run it as? Does the key have a passphrase?

Comment: The key DOES have a passphrase. The script does not run as root in crontab. I made the crontab as my usual user, and the ssh key is for the same user. I do not to run as root because I don't want it to expect any passwords, I just want it to run in the background correctly.

Comment: There's no one in the background to type in the passphrase, and that's why it fails. Make a new key with no passphrase. You can restrict it on the server side to only allow rsync if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add '-i' switch to your ssh command in your command line:

```
rsync --progress -rvze "ssh -i/path/to/ssh_private_key" my_user@myserver:/root_folder folder/
```

Comment: Wouldn't it being better to run the script as `my_user` ? (From the security perspective?)

Comment: @hek2mgl This answers the question of how to pass the ssh key file. It doesn't make the command run as a different user.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, I know, that's why I'm asking. If you would specifiy that the script should run as `my_user`, the `-i` switch will not being required  anymore. And it would be secure. Running the command as root is insecure.

Comment: This isn't quite working for me, and now my cron isn't logging anything. Someone above mentioned this might be because my ssh key has a passphrase?

Comment: @hek2mgl It's required unless your default key has no passphrase or disallows logins, which is less secure and more hassle respectively.

Comment: Perfect, it works now! I did have to remove the ssh key passphrase using ssh-keygen -p and opting for an empty passphrase

Comment: @thatotherguy This has nothing to do with the `-i` option. (at)johncorser, you can omit the `-i` option.

Comment: @hek2mgl you have to specify -i switch unless you always use the default private key filename(i.e. id_rsa), and it's always safer to explicitly specify the key filepath with crontab. my 2 cents.

Comment: @lihao Valid concerns. Thx for that! :)

Answer (score 18):

I know this thread is old, but for the sake of others who stumble on this problem like me, here are your two options:

- pass the key as suggested by lihao,
- add the correct SSH environment variable so that it will pick the correct key, just the same way as it runs in your normal environment.

For the second option, and assuming that your cron job runs with the correct user (otherwise there are more things to set correctly in your environment), just run:

```
env|grep -i ssh
```

There will be a line like:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

The user id might be different for you. From there, you can just add the following lines to your script:

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]
then
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
fi
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're a savour man! :-)

Comment: After hours of searching, this solution finally work!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @jytous answer, typically `env|grep -i ssh` gives you a tmp file:

eg: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-1gJufasJLiXv/agent.3591`

The `/tmp` in the above, refers to a temporary file that will be deleted when **ssh-agent exits or the computer shuts down**.

Therefore, if you have ssh-agent running to manage your keys, try adding this at the beginning of whatever script(s) you call from cron:

```
auth=`find /tmp -user $LOGNAME -type s -name "*agent*" -print 2>/dev/null`
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$auth
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Refer - [Link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=105201)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is for your cron script to run [Keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo:Keychain) before `rsync`:

```
eval $(keychain --agents ssh --eval --noask --quiet)
```

This assumes that you've already run Keychain as the same user in another terminal to add a private key to an active `ssh-agent` process:

```
$ eval $(keychain --agents ssh --eval id_rsa)

 * keychain 2.8.5 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
 * Found existing ssh-agent: 272060
 * Known ssh key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Run `keychain --list` to see keys present in the active SSH agent:

```
$ keychain --list
3072 SHA256:E2IzZ635kapyGwQG0HiZT+5hCv7dh8glpgvz+qN4dsM ubuntu@raspberrypi1 (RSA)
```